# Building an app made with Intel-xdk with Cordova Cli

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ubuntu-16.04, intel-xdk

I'm evaluating Intel-xdk, the idea is using this tool in my IT classes (people from 15 to 18 y.o.), I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed XDK 3759 Linux 32.
A couple of days ago, as I installed an update I also installed nodejs, npm and cordova because as far as june Xdk will no more provide the cloud build service, anyway, after installing android sdk tools, build tools and platform tools, when I try to compile a simple project I've got this error
Error: /home/prof/prova-xdk/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/prof/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: 3: /home/prof/android-sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

  Can someone please explain me the error? May I check my code? But which file? Thanks everybody! Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you update to 3900 (hotfix coming very soon to address login and several other issues) and use the "Cordova export" feature to build apps. The ZIP that is generated by that export can be provided directly to PhoneGap Build, using the one free private slot. This will be a much simpler build process than having your students install node, Cordova CLI and the Android build tools.